# Invalid date for french language

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, datepicker

I got an invalid date when the date is on French. Did i missed something else on this to turn the french date to be value? If the date is on English like "9 May 2014" it will return valid date. Seems like French Dates are not recognized.

Here is my code below:

```
date = '9 Mai 2014';
d = new Date(date);
alert(d);
```

Here is a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/6mAeC/1/)

Comment: You should have a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Passing random date strings do new Date() is generally not a very good idea.

Comment: @Adeneo, Its not really a string but just for example to show. I have a date picker with french language

Comment: If it's a jQuery datepicker it returns a date object if you ask it nicely.

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#page-14

Comment: Did you got any solution @user1149244 I am also facing same issue.?

Comment: I figured this out before. I have to check it back for you.

Answer (score 2):

As described in [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), the Date constructor accept String Date in [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) format or in a version of [ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15).

Date in french are not accepted. Month must be one of  ["Jan" / "Feb" / "Mar" / "Apr" /
"May" / "Jun" / "Jul" / "Aug" /
"Sep" / "Oct" / "Nov" / "Dec"].